# Can't connect to Docker sql for Windows by hostname

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I have next docker compose file (part of it)

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  # DB Server ==========================================================================================================
  mssqlsimple:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer:2017-latest
    volumes:
      - ".\\Prm.DbContext.Application\\FullInit:C:\\data"
    container_name: pbpmssqlsimple
    ports:
      #- "1403:1433"
      - target: 1433
        published: 1403
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "SP_116b626d-ed7e-4f5d123@"

...
```

after command docker-compose up i have instance of sql server and can to connect to it by IP (**172.21.69.132**) or alias id (**0338726df5ba**) from docker config.
[image]

but i can't connect by host name **mssqlsimple** (or pbpmssqlsimple)
fragment config json
[image]

I tried to do it, but failed

1. disable windows firewall
2. connect with port mssqlsimple, 1403
3. used simple syntax for ports "1403:1433"

Tell me please how to solve my problem

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from (the host, another container)?  What's the actual error message you're getting?  Can you show the code that connects to the database and how it's configured?

Comment: I try connect in SQL Server Management Studio with next error      A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)